# Solid angle integral, with legendre polynomials

Tags: integration, legendre-polynomials, solid-angle

I've been trying to solve this question from Jon Mathews Mathematical methods for physics, and I'm honestly very lost, I was given the following hint:

$$
\cos \gamma=\cos \theta \cos \theta^{\prime}+\sin \theta \sin \theta^{\prime} \cos \left(\phi-\phi^{\prime}\right)
$$

And the problem is problem 7-3:

Consider the integral
$$
I=\int d \Omega f(\cos \alpha) g(\cos \beta)
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the angles between the variable direction $\Omega$ and two fixed directions in space. The integral may be written in the form
$$
I=\int d x d y f(x) g(y) K(x, y)
$$
in two ways:

(1) by a change of variable

(2) by expanding $f$ and $g$ in series of Legendre polynomials.
By comparing the two expressions, evaluate the sum
$$
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(2 l+1) P_{l}(x) P_{l}(y) P_{l}(z)
$$